# Alert if Kafka nodes are down

Tags: java, apache-kafka, publish, vert.x

I have been exposed a Kafka nodes and a topic-name. My web server receives a lot of http request data which I need to process them and then push them to kafka. Sometimes, if the kafka nodes are down, then my server still keeps pumping the data, which results in blowing up my memory and my server gets down.

I want is to stop publishing the data if the Kafka is down. My Java sample code is as follows:

```
  static Producer producer;

  Produce() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("request.required.acks","1");
    properties.put("bootstrap.servers","localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094");
    properties.put("enabled","true");
    properties.put("value.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    properties.put("kafka-topic","pixel-server");
    properties.put("batch.size","1000");
    properties.put("producer.type","async");
    properties.put("key.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Produce produce = new Produce();

    produce.send(producer, "pixel-server", "Some time");

  }

  //This method is called lot of times
  public void send(Producer<String, String> producer, String topic, String data) {
    ProducerRecord<String, String> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(topic, data);
    Future<RecordMetadata> response = producer.send(producerRecord, (metadata, exception) -> {
      if (null != exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
      } else {
        System.out.println("Done");
      }
    });
```

I have just abstracted out some sample code. The **send** method is called numerous times. I just want to prevent send any message if the kafka is down. What is the efficient way to tackle this situation.

Comment: If brokers go down, you get exceptions from the Future,which you need to handle. Maybe put a Redis cache to put back pressure between your api and the brokers?  If you're asking for a *monitoring solution*, there's better tools that perform process checking rather than ones you'd write out on your own. Follows no different ways of monitoring a database or website

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I'll try to implement a [circuit breaker](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html). When you hit a reasonable amount of failures while sending your records, circuit breaks and provides some fallback behavior. Once some condition is met (e.g.: some time passed) the circuit close and you'll send records again. Also `vertx.io` comes with it's [own solution](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-circuit-breaker/java/).

Comment: But the issue that I am not being able to identify if the kafka is down or not. If I can find out then I can figure out some solution.

Comment: My thought was it is important if Kafka is up, but it's more important if I can send records to him or not. That's why I suggest circuit breaker pattern. I think monitor Kafka and behave accordingly (you want to do this, am I right?) could be more complicated.

Comment: Yes ur correct, I do not want to monitor kafka at all. But how would I know the failure when a record is sent to kafka is my question?

Comment: The `Future` in your `send` method should aware you by returning an exception when a failure occurs.

Comment: Yea, but its not happening. I am not getting any exception. So that's the problem.

Comment: Not familiar with `Kafka`, but even `response.get()` throws no exception?